# Could IE 8/9/10 remember the last src of an iframe between sessions?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, browser

Need some clarification in this question.
I have an HTML page inside which exists iframe without src. This tag is generated each time main page is loaded. Then if user (for example) came first time to this page - JS on the main page will change src of the iframe to *SOME_URL* (before src was empty):

```
$('#frame_id').attr('src', SOME_URL);
```

Now on my logs I see a lot of records that php script under *SOME_URL* was processed but I don't see appropriate logs that JS changed src of iframe on the main page. NOTE: php script under *SOME_URL* is called from the correct place (from main page of the site). And this is the only place where it could be called.

Is it possible that IE remember the last state (last src) of an iframe (maybe if tag was generated with the whole HTML) between browser's sessions? For example user came to my page, JS changed src of an iframe. then user close the browser (or close tab with my page) and then open browser again on my page. And in this case browser loaded iframe with the last src from previous session and not with the empty src as it should be.

Thanks for those who will clarify this situation

Comment: No. Cookie doesn't store info related to this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you _want_ to remember that src...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue to me. Try adding to the src page that contains the iframe:

```
example.com/pageWithIframe.html?v=SOME_UNIQUE_HASH_FOR_THIS_USER
```

This should avoid caching issues